# glmer - inconsistent convergence issues

Tags: r, mixed-models, convergence

I am starting to build the model that looks like this:

```
model_sim <- glmer(Accuracy ~ x*y*z_scaled + (1 |Participant), 
          binomial(link = "logit"), data = Data)
```

And it failed to converge so I ran the `allFit` function:

```
(model_sim <- allFit(model_sim, maxfun = 1e+05))
```

to see if there were actual reasonable reasons to be concerned, it converged with 5 out 6 optimizers, all with the same value, so I selected the one I always select - bobyqa with 1e+05 iterations but it failed to converge again.
Could anyone explain why this happened? Shouldn't it converge based on the all fit results? What would you do in this situation?

```
$fixef
```

[image]

```
 $llik
      bobyqa                   Nelder_Mead                    nlminbwrap 
      -24286.15               -24286.15                     -24286.15 
 nloptwrap.NLOPT_LN_NELDERMEAD     nloptwrap.NLOPT_LN_BOBYQA 
                -24286.15                     -24286.15 

  $theta
                                     Participant.(Intercept)
  bobyqa                                      0.6872716
  Nelder_Mead                                 0.6872370
  nlminbwrap                                  0.6872456
  nloptwrap.NLOPT_LN_NELDERMEAD               0.6872732
  nloptwrap.NLOPT_LN_BOBYQA                   0.6872732
```

Comment: Can you show use e.g. `summary(model_sim)[c("fixef","llik","theta)]` (by editing your question)?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: @Ben Bolker, should I drop the random structure?

Answer (score 1):

You might be misunderstanding the meaning/purpose of `allFit()` (and maybe the convergence warnings themselves). `allFit()` *doesn't actually change anything*/make anything converge "better" - it just tests whether a range of different optimization algorithms converge on the *same* solution (or sufficiently similar solutions).

Your output shows that all of the available optimizers are converging to the same coefficients, at least to several decimal places (hopefully a difference between a `Probability` coefficient of 0.449 and 0.451 will not make a substantive difference to your conclusions), and that the difference in log-likelihoods is less than 0.005 log-likelihood units (which is small). So my conclusion in this case is that the fit is OK, and it doesn't actually matter which optimizer you use.

Comment: Yes, I understood that. But once I select an optimizer based on the allFit function, and do (model_sim2 <- update(model_sim, glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 1e+05)) it fails to converge. So, should I just ignore the fact that the second model with the optimizer and higher number of iterations fails to converge since the allFit() indicates that when it does converge it converges to similar solutions?

Comment: Does the allFit() provide you information about which optimizers converged? So wouldn't it be expected that by using them, the model would converge?